# ContentObserver onChange

Tags: android, contentobserver

The documentation of the ContentObserver is not clear to me.
On which thread is the onChange of a ContentObserver called?

I checked and it is not the thread where you created the observer. It looks like it is the thread that sends the notification but I didn't find a documentation about it.

Answer (score 18):

The `Thread` that the `ContentObserver.onChange()` method is executed on is the [`ContentObserver` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html#ContentObserver(android.os.Handler))'s [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)'s [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#getLooper())'s [`Thead`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getThread()).

For example, to have it **run on the main UI thread**, the code may look like this:

```
// returns the applications main looper (which runs on the application's 
// main UI thread)
Looper looper = Looper.getMainLooper();

// creates the handler using the passed looper
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);

// creates the content observer which handles onChange on the UI thread
ContentObserver observer = new MyContentObserver(handler);
```

Alternatively, to have it **run on a new worker thread**, the code may look like this:

```
// creates and starts a new thread set up as a looper
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
thread.start();

// creates the handler using the passed looper
Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

// creates the content observer which handles onChange on a worker thread
ContentObserver observer = new MyContentObserver(handler);
```

Or even to have it **run on the current thread**, the code may look like this. Generally this is not what you want because a `Thread` that is looping can't do much else because `Looper.loop()` is a blocking call. Nevertheless:

```
// prepares the looper of the current thread
Looper.prepare();

// creates a handler for the current thread's looper.
Handler handler = new Handler();

// creates the content observer which handles onChange on this thread
ContentObserver observer = new MyContentObserver(handler);

// starts the current thread's looper (blocking call because it's 
// looping, and handling messages forever). the content observer will
// only execute the onChange method while the thread is looping; 
// interrupting Looper.loop() would "break" the content observer.
Looper.loop();
```

Comment: What about the case where `null` is passed to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

In order to assure that the onChange is called on the UI thread, use the correct handler when registering to it:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
ContentObserver observer = new MyContentObserver(handler);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

This old question seems to touch on your issue:

[How to observe contentprovider change? android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237971)

Looks like you should create a new thread, running in its own Service, where the onChange method will be called.