# ContentObserver not working in android

Tags: android, contentobserver

Hi I am trying with the below code.The content resolver is not working with this.Can anyone give an idea

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()){

    @Override public void onChange(    boolean selfChange){

        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

        // Handle change.
        showDialog();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain what "is not working" means. Also, do you have the appropriate "notify" calls in `MyContentProvider`?

Comment: the onchange method is not called here. Sorry I am not aware about the notify calls in contentprovider. Do we really required it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `ContentObserver` only works with a `ContentProvider` that calls [one of the `notifyChange()` methods on a `ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) when the contents of the provider change. If the `ContentProvider` does not call `notifyChange()`, the `ContentObserver` will not be notified about changes.

Comment: Can I user ContentObserver as an alternative of FileObserver as FileObserver is not working in Android 11 and above. Any small example would be appreciated. I want to listen for any files added in selected or subdirectory.

Comment: Ok no worries, thank you for your response. Will keep you posted once I try.

Answer (score 9):

## Problem

The problem I experienced was that the `ContentObserver.onChange()` method never got called because the `ContentObserver`'s `Handler`'s `Looper` was initialized improperly. I forgot to call `Looper.loop()` after calling `Looper.prepare()`...this lead to the `Looper` not consuming events and invoking `ContentObserver.onChange()`.

## Solution

The solution is to properly create and initialize a `Handler` and `Looper` for the `ContentObserver`:

```
// creates and starts a new thread set up as a looper
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
thread.start();

// creates the handler using the passed looper
Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

// creates the content observer which handles onChange on a worker thread
ContentObserver observer = new MyContentObserver(handler);
```

[**useful SO post about controlling which thread `ContentObserver.onChange()` is executed on.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380914/contentobserver-onchange/35261443#35261443)

Comment: Thank you, was stuck on the exact same issue!