# Android Observe and notify Content Provider Change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, notifydatasetchanged, contentobserver

I am developing an android application where I use androids content provider :-**android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI** to list the image files. Now I whenever this content provider data gets changed , I want to Toast a message to user. How can I do that.

Please note that I am using androids builtin Content Provide and not my own custom Content Provider.

I don't know but can this thing be solved using notifychange , or getContentResolver.notifyChange.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can find your answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237971/how-to-observe-contentprovider-change-android

Comment: @Hayk Petrosyan No, I have gone through this link, but no help

Comment: What do you mean "no help"? That's how you do it.

Comment: I mean that in yhis link its making his own custom content provider

Comment: The answer is the same, though, whether it's your Provider, or the platform's.

Comment: @MikeM.   Thanks, I only had this doubt that creating own content provider and using platform's provider would make any difference or not. Now I am able to Toast message to user. Thanks

Comment: @Hayk Petrosyan Thanks, I only had this doubt that creating own content provider and using platform's provider would make any difference or not. Now I am able to Toast message to user. Thanks –

Comment: @MikeM. But now I have one question that whenever I delete an image file,  I get Toast message 4-5 times. This may be mainly because in Content Provider 4-5 different dataset may have got changed.  But how to make my app show to user only one toast for an event?

Comment: I haven't done anything with the `MediaStore` Provider, but if it's anything like the SMS Provider, it "moves" things just by changing column values in its database, so your Observer is going to fire each time that happens. You'll have to find out which column value change actually means delete, and only act on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your own ContentObserver class?, I think you need to implement Observable class and handle change event there, than you can show your toasts easily