# Broadcastreceiver for a downloaded image

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver

Basically I want to set a `Broadcastreceiver` that gets triggered when the user downloads an image into gallery/phone from chrome, facebook, twitter..etc

when the photo is finished downloading , and the actions is triggered, I want access to the downloaded image for extra work such as editing and stuff..!

I'm thinking this can be accomplished by `Broadcastreceiver`, that listens for the image and then do the actions that needed..!

I've tried to search for action to be added in the `Manifest` inside the receiver `intent-filter` , but I don't which one?

```
<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <inent-filter>
       <action android:name="??????"/>
    </inent-filter>
```

I've read almost all the intent action [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), but couldn't find the one..!

Answer (score 1):

Older android versions used

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NewPictureReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

to get informed that the camera has shot a new photo. I do not know if this get also triggered by a downloaded image.

taken from https://github.com/M66B/FineGeotag/ that adds gps data to jpg

This [will not work any more with newer android version.](https://github.com/M66B/FineGeotag/pull/7)

Not a working solution but some hints how to find a solution.

The android media scanner updates the android internal media database and you can [register an image-contentprovder-observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237971/how-to-observe-contentprovider-change-android) that tells your that media database `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` has changed. you can query then the media db `order by last modify date descending`. The top rows should be the new images.

Comment: hmm, ok, I'll try to dig deep about the hint you mentioned.! thanks a lot.!