# Share Image from Gallery via My App in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, intentfilter

I want to share an image from the phone gallery. My app should be in sharing options. How can I do that in Xamarin Forms. Give me suggestion to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

#### in Android ,add the following code in **Manifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" android:scheme="http"  /> 
    <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" android:scheme="http"  />
    //. . . add all mimetype which your app support here
</intent-filter>
```

#### in iOS

Add the following code in Info.plist .

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
                <string>public.content</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

For more type you can check [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1).

Comment: How to receive the image from the gallery when clicking on my app(in that share option)? Please Guide.

Comment: is it possible to receive an image using broadcast receiver? if Yes means Give me an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435699/broadcastreceiver-for-a-downloaded-image